# Why the return value of my function is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, return

guys, I'm just starting in the coding world. Now I'm learning JavaScript, so I have a problem, I have a function that is going to ask the user for the name.

Then I want to create another function using the name for ask for an integer, so when I try to call the return values from the first function is giving me undefined.

This is my code:

```
function getUsername() {
    var f1CustomerName;

    f1CustomerName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Type Here");
    // window.alert("f1CustomerName is: " + f1CustomerName );

    if ( f1CustomerName == null ) {
        return;
    } else if( f1CustomerName == "Type Here" || f1CustomerName == "" ) {
        return;
    } else {
        //window.alert("Hello " + f1CustomerName + "!");
        return f1CustomerName;
    }
}

var nameUser = getUsername();

// ...

function getinteger(nameUser) {
    var integer=prompt(nameUser + " Please enter an integer");
    window.alert("Hello this is your integer: " + integer + "!");
}

getinteger();
```

Comment: what is enter code here, please clear your question and if possible share any online reference of you working code, somewhere on https://codepen.io/ or other online tools to share code.

Answer (score 2):

In your version of the function you did not return anything. The following should work:

```js
function getUsername()
  {
     var f1CustomerName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Type Here");
     if( f1CustomerName == null || f1CustomerName == "Type Here") return "";
     else return f1CustomerName;
 }
 console.log(getUsername());
```

Here is an even shorter version of the same. As you only have one variable in your function it makes sense to shorten its name too (to `nam`). You can even 
directly use the return value of the `getUsername()` function directly as a function argument in your `getinteger()` function call.

(But since you have `nameUser` in your `getinteger()` function's parameter list you can *not* access the global variable `userName` from within that function.)

```js
function getUsername(){
  var nam = prompt("Please enter your name", "Type Here");
  return nam == null||nam=="Type Here" ? "" : nam ;
}
function getinteger(nameUser) {
    var integer=prompt(nameUser + " Please enter an integer");
    window.alert("Hello "+nameUser+", this is your integer: " + integer + "!");
}

getinteger(getUsername());
```

Comment: Thanks, i just call my variable nameUser when i called the function getInteger

Answer (score 0):

You should give the function the variable of nameUser to use it when calling it in the last line:

```
getinteger(nameUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` when no value is explicitly returned.

Your existing code can be drastically simplified.

```js
function getUsername() {
  return prompt("Please enter your name") || null;
}
function getinteger(nameUser) {
  if (!nameUser) {return;}
  const integer = prompt(`${nameUser} Please enter an integer`);
  window.alert(`Hello this is your integer: ${integer}!`); 
}

getinteger(
  getUsername()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, is cause that is just the beggining of my project i had the the loop in getusername to check any empty string or to the cancel button works, but thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just return values from your if-else statements

```
function getUsername() {
    var f1CustomerName;

    f1CustomerName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Type Here");
    //window.alert("f1CustomerName is: " + f1CustomerName );

    if (f1CustomerName == null) {
        return f1CustomerName;
    } else if (f1CustomerName == "Type Here" || f1CustomerName == "") {
        return f1CustomerName;
    } else {
        //window.alert("Hello " + f1CustomerName + "!");
        return f1CustomerName;
    }
}
```

Also you should pass some argument to your getinteger function.

Comment: Thanks, i just call my variable nameUser when i called the function getInteger